# How to calculate and group columns using Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to make a table of a soccer championship (leaderboard) from a table of matches which I should sum the total of goals when playing at home and group it, but I'm getting the error message: "Unknown column 'homeGoals' in 'field list'". How can I get that column?

```
e.g.
| homeTeam | homeGoals | awayGoals  | awayTeam |
|  Arsenal |    3      x     0      |  Chelsea |
|  Everton |    1      x     4      |  Arsenal |
|  Arsenal |    1      x     0      |Liverpool |
|  Everton |    1      x     1      |  Chelsea |

response (homeGoals):
|  team  |  goals  |
--------------------
| Arsenal|    4    |
| Everton|    2    |
```

```
public async getHomeGoals(): Promise<ILBoard> {
    const leaderboard = await this.matchModel.findAll({
      attributes: [
        'team',
        [sequelize.fn('sum', sequelize.col('homeGoals')), 'goals'],
      ],
      group: 'homeTeam',
      raw: true,
    });
    return leaderboard as unknown as ILBoard;
  }
```

**MatchModel**

```
MatchModel.init({
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  homeTeam: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  homeGoals: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  awayTeam: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  awayGoals: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
  },
}, {
  underscored: true,
  sequelize: db,
  modelName: 'matches',
  timestamps: false,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
const matchModel = await MatchModel.findAll({
        group: ['homeTeam'],
        attributes: ['homeTeam', [literal(`SUM("homeGoals")`), 'homeGoals']]
    });
```